# MATLAB cellarray doesn't hold references?

Tags: arrays, matlab, reference

I have a number of vectors with semantic identifiers (e.g. `inputs = [...]`). I want to put them into a cell array so that I can iterate over the lot of them. But when I try:

```
inputs(1).myfield = 2 % some arbitrary value
mycellarray{1} = inputs
inputs(1).myfield = 3 % some arbitrary value
assert(mycellarray{1}(1).myfield == inputs(1).myfield)
% => FAIL
```

The cell array says that `{1}` holds a `1x5 MyObject array`, but apparently it doesn't reference the same object as `inputs`.

How can I achieve my aim? (I can't put my vectors into a matrix, as the vectors aren't of the same length.)

Comment: Matlab has no references, things are copied

Answer (score 0):

As in comment noted in Matlab objects passed by value. But the following trick can be done in GNU Octave (in Matlab I'm not sure):

```
ref = @(name) @(index) evalin('caller',sprintf('%s(%d)',name,index));

inputs(1).myfield = 2; 
mycellarray{1} = ref('inputs');
inputs(1).myfield = 3; 
assert(mycellarray{1}(1).myfield == inputs(1).myfield)
```

`ref` is a function that gets a `name` and returns a function handle that gets an `index` and evaluate the expression `name(index)`

So when we write `mycellarray{1} = ref('inputs');` we store a function handle in the cellarray .

Then when we write `mycellarray{1}` the function handle `@(index) evalin('caller',sprintf('%s(%d)',name,index))` returned.

When we write `mycellarray{1}(1)` the expression `inputs(1)` is evaluated and its result returned.

When we write `mycellarray{1}(1).myfield` field `myfield` returned (doesn't work in Matlab)

**Note**: with the above method only value of `myfield` can be retrieved but cannot be assigned.

Comment: In addition to noting that MATLAB is call-by-value it is worth noting one more thing. In MATLAB there is no way to store the memory location as a variable either. The value of a variable is always the value of what its stored in this variable.